# Can I pass more arguments to optimize() function in R

Tags: r, optimization

The optimize function is only designed to handle one function argument as I understand it.
But sometimes a function can depend on different input ranges of variables and parameters.

for example:

```
x.r<-rnorm(100)
y<-function(x,p) -x^2+p*1/exp(x^3)
optimize(y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1])
```

x.r. the domain of x being passed to y can change from sample to sample. Instead of using a generic x, I want to be able to draw from many x.r domains of values to run y over. Is there some way to modify the optimize function so that I could pass both y, the function, and x it's domain variables as well as the optimize parameter(s) p?

With the above I get an error:

```
> optimize(y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1])
Error in p * 1 : 'p' is missing
```

edit:
per suggestion below (which makes sense... but)
I tried.

```
x.r<-rnorm(100)
p<-seq(-5,5,1)
y<-function(x,p) -x^2+p*1/exp(x^3)
optimize(y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1],p)
```

results was:
Error in p * 1 : 'p' is missing

Also,

```
> optimize(y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1],p,x.r)
Error in optimize(y, upper = range(x.r)[2], lower = range(x.r)[1], p,  : 
  invalid function value in 'optimize'
```

any other ideas?

edit 2:
per comments below a loop would work, but seems like an odd way to approach it.
I'm not sure if it's uniquely taking the x.r domain into account either.

```
x.r<-rnorm(100)
p<-seq(-5,5,1)
y<-function(p=p,x=x.r) -x^2+p*1/exp(x^3)
for(v in p){
print(optimize(y,upper=range(p)[2],lower=range(p)[1],p=v))}

> for(v in p){
+ print(optimize(y,upper=range(p)[2],lower=range(p)[1],p=v))}
$minimum
[1] -4.999944

$objective
[1] -9.637547e+54

$minimum
[1] -4.999944

$objective
...
```

Comment: Try something like `optimize(y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1],p=some_variable)` the idea is to add `p` parameter at the end and pass to it any variable you want

Comment: I edited to try that. I also tried several variants (inc. making p as the first arg to y, since optimize grabs first argument by default). The key that I'm trying to get is passing different x domains to the optimize.

Comment: you should add the argument as `p=3` for example

Comment: @pat I think you need to call optimize for ecah p.

Comment: @iTech That works, but doesn't make sense to me. I want to find what value of all possible p values gives the optimum (given f(p,x), where x is domain range). Isn't that returning only a value given 1 p only?@agstudy... maybe that is it. So I need a loop to do it then? I was hoping for a simple vector based method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call `optimise` over p

```
x.r <- rnorm(100)
p   <- seq(-5,5,1)
y<-function(x,p) -x^2+ p/exp(x^3)
ll <- lapply(p,function(i)
         optimize(y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1],p=i))

ll[[which.min(sapply(ll,'[[','minimum'))]]

$minimum
[1] -2.14628

$objective
[1] -98357.67
```

Of course if `maximum = TRUE` the last becomes

```
ll[[which.max(sapply(ll,'[[','maximum'))]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way out of this which works even when the thing you are calling doesn't allow you to specify extra named parameters that are passed on to the function is to create a function-generating function that generates a function with a given p.

```
yp <- function(p){force(p);function(x){-x^2+p*1/exp(x^3)}}
yp1=yp(1)
yp2=yp(2)
```

and now the `yp` functions are just a function of x:

```
> yp1(0)
[1] 1
> yp2(0)
[1] 2
```

so your loop becomes:

```
x.r <- rnorm(100)
pv   <- seq(-5,5,1)

ll <- lapply(pv,function(p){
        Y = yp(p)
        optimize(Y,upper=range(x.r)[2],lower=range(x.r)[1])
        })
```

which is looping over the `pv` vector and putting each value in `p` to create a function `Y` based on that value. Nothing else (apart from `upper` and `lower`) is passed into `optimize`.